# Retrieving a Bearer token using Microsoft Identity for an ASP.NET core web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, postman

I am trying to request a bearer token from Azure to hit an endpoint on my ASP.NET core web application. I am using `Microsoft.Identity` platform to authenticate users to the web app which works just fine, but when I try and hit my web apps endpoints with something like PostMan I get the HTML of the Microsoft sign-in page returned to me...

I am able to get the expected response when I switch my authentication over to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` (and configure AAD accordingly), but the reason I do not want to use JWT auth is that the web app needs to authenticate azure active directory users using role-based access. As far as I'm aware, that isn't an option when using JwtBearer auth?

I think my issue has to do with how I have configured AAD (Azure Active Directory), as it is not entirely clear how I need to configure my app registration I am using to authenticate within postman alongside the app registration I am using for defining my web apps authentication. To start off - I'll paste some code snippets below to demonstrate how my web app is configured for `Microsoft.Identity` auth.

Below is my Startup.cs file where I've configured Microsoft Identity:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllRoles", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireRole(new[] { "ADMIN", "USER" }));
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireRole(new[] { "ADMIN" }));
                options.AddPolicy("User", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireRole(new[] { "USER" }));
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMvcOptions(options => { })
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the controller I am trying to hit:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Demo.Controllers
{
    [Authorize("AllRoles")]
    //[AllowAnonymous] // <-- This works fine
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HealthCheckController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> CheckConnectionToWebApp()
        {
            return "You've connected!";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant portion of my appsettings.json

```json
...
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "qualified.domain.name", // Currently not set, unsure if this needs to be?
    "TenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", // Set to a legitimate value in my code
    "ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", // Set to a legitimate value in my code
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
...
```

I have two app registrations set up... One that defines the authentication for my web app (its client ID  sits in the appsettings.json above). When I say 'defines the authentication' I mean it literally defines the application roles I have listed in my `startup.cs` (ADMIN & USER) under the *Manage->App Roles* tab in AAD. User authentication works exactly as expected - users are denied access/allowed access to the UI pages based on the role they are assigned in AAD.

The second app registration I set up to use for authenticating postman to my web app. This app registration is not detailed anywhere in the C# webapp's code. It is configured to have the custom 'ADMIN' role assigned to it under the *Manage->API Permissions* tab in AAD. I assumed adding this API Permission would allow the app registration to gain access to the web app, but that does not seem to be the case... Below is the PostMan request I am trying to use to hit my Web Apps endpoint.

The PostMan request to retrieve a bearer token (this will return a token successfully):
`POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/token`

```json
client_id:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 // Client ID of a secondary app registration I created & granted 'ADMIN' (where 'ADMIN' is my custom role defined in my Startup) API permissions too.
client_secret:xxx_xxxxxx-xxx_xxx__-xxx
grant_type:client_credentials
resource:api://00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 // The application ID URI of the app registration defined on the app registration for my web app (the one used by the c# web app, which is defined in the appsettings.json).
```

The request I make to my web app using the token acquired above:
`GET https://localhost:44304/api/healthcheck` *(with the bearer token in the header)*
**EXPECTED RESULT**:

```json
Status: 200 OK
Body: You've connected!
```

**ACTUAL RESULT**:

```html
Status: 200 OK
Body: 
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://aadcdn.msauth.net" crossorigin>
    <meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msauth.net">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msftauth.net">

    <meta name="PageID" content="ConvergedSignIn" />
    <meta name="SiteID" content="" />
    <meta name="ReqLC" content="1033" />
    <meta name="LocLC" content="en-US" />

    <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />

    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://login.microsoftonline.com/jsdisabled" />
    </noscript>



    <meta name="robots" content="none" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
$Config={ ...
```

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get any response other than the above HTML sign-on page returned too me. Even to get a 401 response would be better than what I am currently receiving. Any ideas on what I may be overlooking?

Comment: How do you plan to connect to the API? Is it your client backend as machine to machine or does the API expect the calls to be on behalf of a client user?

Comment: Have you tried this sample?  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles#add-authorization-using-app-roles--roles-claims-to-an-aspnet-core-web-app-thats-signs-in-users-with-the-microsoft-identity-platform

Comment: This may be the reason for the tool, do not use postman, try another tool.

Comment: @StanleyGong thank you for the link - I don't think that is what I want though. The link describes what I already have configured, but not how to configure a web app using OpenID Connect to authenticate via a bearer token or something similar. (Unless I missed that part?)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils the API expects to be called by an external software service, so something like ServiceNow or a separate script that would need to authenticate to it in order to invoke a REST request against the web apps endpoints.

Comment: @CarlZhao I also wrote a small C# script to invoke a request against my web app, I got the same results returned to me. I don't see why it would be a Postman issue? Does Postman not do well with certain requests?

Comment: @Undead, I think it's not really postman but the oauth flow. If you were doing machine to machine, you'd use client_credentials which obviously does not need a signed in user. You'd then get a bearer token and use it directly. OIDC and its middleware is different. I've got a sample project going and I'm seeing the same thing. I'll try to see if I can configure it to work with postman later tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Client credentials flow doesn't require a user login.

There must be something wrong with configuration in your API side.

Please follow this sample to implement the service-to-service authentication in ASP.NET core application: [A .NET Core daemon console application calling a Web API with its own identity](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi)